# How to install a Java application as a service

Tags: java, windows, service, java-service-wrapper

I have a Java Application written that forwards selected files to an ssh server.  I want this application to be automatically run every time windows starts.

I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times, and I have followed those leads.  I have tried Java Service Wrapper (which is no longer accessible because of a dns problem), Apache Daemon, and JSL.  Though I have at times been able to get the application installed as a service, I have never been able to get it to run properly on boot, or even start it manually from the command line.

My question is whether anyone is aware of a full first step through final step tutorial of how to make this work.  I have come across a few things, but they all either assume that you have implemented something that they do not explain how to implement, or rely on applications that I do not have installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use Java Service Wrapper to install as windows or linux service: http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

~> create one runnable JAR to your app.

~> Download the proper service wrapper (they are diffrent to windows and linux)

~> Configure the service in wrapper.conf

Important: set `wrapper.java.classpath` correct (your jar must be here too)
Set `wrapper.java.mainclass` with `org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp`
Set `wrapper.app.parameter.1` with the name of your main class, for example:

```
wrapper.app.parameter.1=Main
```

~> Test the service as console (windows bat)

Comment: Is there no more to it?  do I need to implement a specific interface or something or should I be able to simply install and run the service? @Sérgio Michels

Comment: Yep, I don't implement any specific interface. Just it should be enough beacuse WrapperSimpleApp do the work.

Comment: Where exactly is the wrapper.conf that I need to edit?  in {WRAPPER_HOME}/conf there is one, but there is also a wrapper.conf.in in {WRAPPER_HOME}/src/conf.  can you explain what the *.in files are for? @Sérgio Michels

Comment: And if you want to do some specific stuff on the stop of service, add Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook().

Comment: @ewok, I don't know why the extension is "in" but I edit the {WRAPPER_HOME}/conf