# Linux start-up script for java application

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, startup, redhat

I have Jar file to run in Linux using this command:

```
java -jar SyslogAgent_01.jar 192.168.2.154 1998 D:/apachelog.log ApacheLog 13
```

Can anyone let me know how to create script and implement this process automatically while we restart our computer? In windows we use services but how about linux?
Can u provide to me the script and step to do that since i am really new in Linux...

Linux : RHat, Ubuntu

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run the app as linux daemon (service) checkout Java Wrapper: http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Check this answer too (is for windows, but for linux changes a little bit): [How to install a Java application as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352291/how-to-install-a-java-application-as-a-service/7352350#7352350)

Comment: I have been using the tanuki software for 2 years. However in my case i cannot add extra library since this is production server...

Answer (score 4):

I would start with this template for a startup script rename the `SCRIPT_HOME` to proper path and call this file without any extensions, then in SSH run this command.

```
chkconfig –add javaserver
```

Note the `javaserver` in the `chkconfig` is how you called the file below, (no extensions or it wont work).

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# javaserver: Startup script for Any Server Application.
#
# chkconfig: 35 80 05
# description: Startup script for Any Server Application.

SCRIPT_HOME=/var/java_server;
export SCRIPT_HOME

start() {
        echo -n "Starting Java Server: "
        $SCRIPT_HOME/run.sh start
        sleep 2
        echo "done"
}

stop() {
        echo -n "Stopping Java Server: "
        $SCRIPT_HOME/run.sh stop
        echo "done"
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
        start)
                start
                ;;
        stop)
                stop
                ;;
        restart)
                stop
                start
                ;;
        *)
                echo $"Usage: javaserver {start|stop|restart}"
                exit
esac
```

Now here is the script the run.sh (this can be used instead of the template but I find it easier to make the template script small and unchangeable link to my main script so I never have to touch it again.

The script below is one of a very few scripts I found that actually can restart a java program without turning off all the java programs you currently have running, this one only targets the program it opened in the first place so it will never make any mistakes, never had it fail on me, run on user `root` no problem.
Runs your program in the background forever too (no need to keep SSH opened).

This is the `run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: 345 99 05 
# description: Java deamon script
#
# A non-SUSE Linux start/stop script for Java daemons.
#
# Set this to your Java installation
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/

scriptFile=$(readlink -fn $(type -p $0))                                        # the absolute, dereferenced path of this script file
scriptDir=$(dirname $scriptFile)                                                    # absolute path of the script directory
serviceNameLo="javaserver"                                                       # service name with the first letter in lowercase
serviceName="JavaServer"                                                           # service name
serviceUser="root"                                                                           # OS user name for the service
serviceGroup="root"                                                                         # OS group name for the service
applDir="/var/java_server"                                       # home directory of the service application
serviceUserHome="/home/$serviceUser"                                      # home directory of the service user
serviceLogFile="/var/log/$serviceNameLo.log"                            # log file for StdOut/StdErr
maxShutdownTime=15                                                                     # maximum number of seconds to wait for the daemon to terminate normally
pidFile="/var/run/$serviceNameLo.pid"                                        # name of PID file (PID = process ID number)
javaCommand="java"                                                                       # name of the Java launcher without the path
javaArgs="MyJavaAppClass"                                                                  # arguments for Java launcher
javaCommandLine="$JAVA_HOME$javaCommand $javaArgs"   # command line to start the Java service application
javaCommandLineKeyword="MyJavaAppClass"                                   # a keyword that occurs on the commandline, used to detect an already running service process and to distinguish it from others

# Makes the file $1 writable by the group $serviceGroup.
function makeFileWritable {
   local filename="$1"
   touch $filename || return 1
   chgrp $serviceGroup $filename || return 1
   chmod g+w $filename || return 1
   return 0; }

# Returns 0 if the process with PID $1 is running.
function checkProcessIsRunning {
   local pid="$1"
   if [ -z "$pid" -o "$pid" == " " ]; then return 1; fi
   if [ ! -e /proc/$pid ]; then return 1; fi
   return 0; }

# Returns 0 if the process with PID $1 is our Java service process.
function checkProcessIsOurService {
   local pid="$1"
   if [ "$(ps -p $pid --no-headers -o comm)" != "$javaCommand" ]; then return 1; fi
   grep -q --binary -F "$javaCommandLineKeyword" /proc/$pid/cmdline
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then return 1; fi
   return 0; }

# Returns 0 when the service is running and sets the variable $pid to the PID.
function getServicePID {
   if [ ! -f $pidFile ]; then return 1; fi
   pid="$(<$pidFile)"
   checkProcessIsRunning $pid || return 1
   checkProcessIsOurService $pid || return 1
   return 0; }

function startServiceProcess {
   cd $applDir || return 1
   rm -f $pidFile
   makeFileWritable $pidFile || return 1
   makeFileWritable $serviceLogFile || return 1
   cmd="nohup $javaCommandLine >>$serviceLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile"
   # Don't forget to add -H so the HOME environment variable will be set correctly.
   #sudo -u $serviceUser -H $SHELL -c "$cmd" || return 1
   su --session-command="$javaCommandLine >>$serviceLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile" $serviceUser || return 1
   sleep 0.1
   pid="$(<$pidFile)"
   if checkProcessIsRunning $pid; then :; else
      echo -ne "\n$serviceName start failed, see logfile."
      return 1
   fi
   return 0; }

function stopServiceProcess {
   kill $pid || return 1
   for ((i=0; i<maxShutdownTime*10; i++)); do
      checkProcessIsRunning $pid
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
         rm -f $pidFile
         return 0
         fi
      sleep 0.1
      done
   echo -e "\n$serviceName did not terminate within $maxShutdownTime seconds, sending SIGKILL..."
   kill -s KILL $pid || return 1
   local killWaitTime=15
   for ((i=0; i<killWaitTime*10; i++)); do
      checkProcessIsRunning $pid
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
         rm -f $pidFile
         return 0
         fi
      sleep 0.1
      done
   echo "Error: $serviceName could not be stopped within $maxShutdownTime+$killWaitTime seconds!"
   return 1; }

function startService {
   getServicePID
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo -n "$serviceName is already running"; RETVAL=0; return 0; fi
   echo -n "Starting $serviceName   "
   startServiceProcess
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then RETVAL=1; echo "failed"; return 1; fi
   echo "started PID=$pid"
   RETVAL=0
   return 0; }

function stopService {
   getServicePID
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo -n "$serviceName is not running"; RETVAL=0; echo ""; return 0; fi
   echo -n "Stopping $serviceName   "
   stopServiceProcess
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then RETVAL=1; echo "failed"; return 1; fi
   echo "stopped PID=$pid"
   RETVAL=0
   return 0; }

function checkServiceStatus {
   echo -n "Checking for $serviceName:   "
   if getServicePID; then
    echo "running PID=$pid"
    RETVAL=0
   else
    echo "stopped"
    RETVAL=3
   fi
   return 0; }

function main {
   RETVAL=0
   case "$1" in
      start)                                               # starts the Java program as a Linux service
         startService
         ;;
      stop)                                                # stops the Java program service
         stopService
         ;;
      restart)                                             # stops and restarts the service
         stopService && startService
         ;;
      status)                                              # displays the service status
         checkServiceStatus
         ;;
      *)
         echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
         exit 1
         ;;
      esac
   exit $RETVAL
}

main $1
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is not recommended to sudo items like this, it can be accomplished by the following:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Place the following in the cron:

```
@reboot java -jar SyslogAgent_01.jar 192.168.2.154 1998 D:/apachelog.log ApacheLog 13
```

Comment: It seem happens only when you reboot... How to start immediately too? I cant restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Uhh first you might want to edit out your local ip thats more information that your giving out. Anyhow just open up a new document type this

```
 #!/bin/bash

 #put your commands in here
```

Save then open up terminal and type chmod +x nameofscript

Im not sure about ubuntu but on arch we have a place to run commands on startup.
My advice is to goto system->prefernces->start up applications or something along that line its in that menu I know.

Type the path to the script ie
/home/username/scrips/myawesomescript

Comment: Not sure why a local IP would be a security issue...  It's clearly inside a class C subnet (or some other variant), which means it's behind a firewall of some type.  Nobody's going to be able to access it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to create a little shell script in /etc/init.d and make symlinks to /etc/rc2.d and /etc/rc5.d. The contents could be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = start ] ; then
    cd /put_your_workdir_here
    /usr/bin/java -jar SyslogAgent_01.jar 192.168.2.154 1998 D:/apachelog.log ApacheLog 13 &
fi
```

Notice that you start your program in background (& at the end of the commandline)

Comment: I tried already yr method, it was failed... Not sure where is wrong

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a unix shell script file, that will automate the job for you.
Here are the steps to create the script file: 
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/shell-script-for-jar-utility-769461/